# Where to find exe file after installation

Tags: linux

I have downloaded zend framework from the synaptic download manager, i can't see the main exe file like we find in the windows(Start->Programs) , i am new to linux so please walk me through this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From the [Synaptic HOWTO](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto):

> **Locating software on your system**
>
> Synaptic can tell you about every file that belongs to a software package it knows about and show you where it is located on your system. Search the database for the software package you are interested in and select it in Synaptic's main window. Next, click on the Installed Files tab to see a list of all files and where they are.

Comment: No actually how do i run the exe file in linux